# V-Model is not Reactive (Vue3)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vee-validate

I have an string input Component, which passes the inputted data back to the parent component, and stores it in a Form Object.

This was working fine, until I began to use a Validation Library (Vee-Validate), I'm trying to retrace my changes, but cannot seem to solve this issue without breaking the validator. I've copied the relevant code below.

Parent Component:

```
<template>
  <form class="form" @submit.prevent="submitFormData">
    <BaseInput
              v-model="form.salutation.firstName"
              type="text"
              class="text-class"
              label="case_file.table.first_name"
              :required="true"
            />
  </form>
</template>

 const form = reactive({
  salutation: {
    firstName: ""
  },
});
```

Child Component:

```
 <template>
  <div class="form-control">
    <label class="label">
      <span class="label-text">{{ $t(`${labelName}`) }}</span>
    </label>
    <input
      type="text"
      class="input input-bordered"
      :value="value"
      @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
      v-on="validationListeners"
    />
    <span>{{ errorMessage }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useField } from "vee-validate";
import { reactive, computed } from "vue";
import { toRefs } from "@vue/reactivity";
import { ref, watch } from "vue";
import { useParticipantStore } from "@/store/participant";
const participantStore = useParticipantStore();

const props = defineProps({
  label: {
    type: [String, Boolean],
    default: false,
  },
  modelValue: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  required: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
});

const labelName = ref(props.label);
const localInputValue = ref(props.modelValue);

function validateField(value) {
  if (!value && props.required) {
    return "This is required";
  }

  return true;
}

const { errorMessage, value, handleChange } = useField(
  "fieldName",
  validateField,
  {
    validateOnValueUpdate: false,
  }
);

const validationListeners = computed(() => {
  // If the field is valid or have not been validated yet
  // lazy
  if (!errorMessage.value) {
    return {
      blur: handleChange,
      change: handleChange,
      input: (e) => handleChange(e, false),
    };
  }

  // Aggressive
  return {
    blur: handleChange,
    change: handleChange,
    input: handleChange, // only switched this
  };
});
</script>
```

Comment: in such case try using  `@input` event listener and `:value` binding instead of using `v-model`.

Answer (score 1):

With this TextInput component:

- `value` does not need to be a prop
- Just emit the `update:modelValue` event to the parent (this should
  be enough)
- For the `required` validation, the browser will help us if we manage the form submit and input attributes properly.
- IMHO, other validations should go in the form component rather than the `input` component. the input should only open the gate for `errorMessages` to render.
- Also, if we have the error messages object (reactive) in the form component, we can determine the submit button state easily.

This does not include vee-validate code but I think you can embed it easily. I feel vee validation should go inside the form component.

```html
<template>
    <div class="form-control">
        <label class="label">
            <span class="label-text">{{ labelName }}</span>
        </label>
        <input
            type="text"
            class="input input-bordered"
            :value="tv"
            :required="required"
            @input="updateModelValue"
            @change="$emit('change', $event.target.value)"
            @focus="$emit('focus', $event.target.value)"
            @blur="$emit('blur', $event.target.value)"
            @keyup="$emit('keyup', $event.target.value)"
        >
        <span>{{ errorMessage }}</span>
    </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import {ref, defineProps, defineEmits} from "vue"


const emit = defineEmits([
    "update:modelValue",
    "change",
    "blur",
    "focus",
    "keyup",
])

const tv = ref("")

defineProps({
    labelName: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },
    errorMessage: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },
    required: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
})

const updateModelValue = ($event) => {
    tv.value = $event.target.value
    emit("update:modelValue", $event.target.value)
}

</script>
```

And this is in the Parent component:

```html
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
    <TextInput
      v-model="form.salutation.firstName"
      label-name="First Name"
      :error-message="formErrors.salutation.firstName"
      required
      @keyup="validateFirstName"
    />
    <button
      type="submit"
      :disabled="formErrors.salutation.firstName"
    >
      Submit
    </button>
   </form>
</template>
<script setup>
  import {reactive, watch} from "vue"
  
  const form = reactive({
    salutation: {
        firstName: "",
    }
  })
  const formErrors = reactive({
    salutation: {
        firstName: null,
    }
  })

  const validateFirstName = () => {
    if (form.salutation.firstName && form.salutation.firstName.length < 3) {
        formErrors.salutation.firstName = "First name must be at least 3 characters"
        return false
    } else {
        formErrors.salutation.firstName = null
        return true
    }
  }

  const submitForm = () => {
    console.log(form.salutation.firstName)
  }
</script>
```

This should make your form:

- not submittable when empty (required validation)
- `show|hide` error messages on `keydown`

Comment: Unfortunately the validation does not work here.

Comment: I've upated the answer with validation from my POV. please do have a look. hope this helps ;)